# Concurrency with aiohttp server

Tags: async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import time

from aiohttp import web

logging.getLogger('aiohttp').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('aiohttp').addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr))

def handle_sync(request):
    web.web_logger.debug('Sync begin')
    time.sleep(10)
    web.web_logger.debug('Sync end')
    return web.Response(text='Synchronous hello')


async def handle_async(request):
    web.web_logger.debug('Async begin')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    web.web_logger.debug('Async end')
    return web.Response(text='Asynchronous hello')


async def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_get('/sync/', handle_sync)
    app.router.add_get('/async/', handle_async)

    srv = await loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '0.0.0.0', 8080)
    return srv

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

I would expect 2 behaviors:

- when hitting twice the `/sync/` url, with let's say a 2-seconds interval, the overall time spent is 20 seconds since we have one server in one thread, and a blocking call
- an overall time of 12 seconds when hitting twice the `/async/` url the same way (these calls are asynchronous, right?)

But it appears that both cases last 20 seconds, can someone please explain me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to observe the benefits using async here, you will need to send the two separate request at (almost) the same time.

The `await` call simply means the function yields control over to the event loop so that if any other events occur, they can be handled without blocking. If you do send two requests at the same time to the async endpoint, you will see that each of them finishes around 10 seconds. This is because both requests are handled at the same time: the first request does not block the server from handling another request.

However if you send two requests in a similar fashion to the sync endpoint, the second request would take 20 seconds. This is because the sync endpoint blocks on the first request and can not start serving the second request until the first one is finished.

Comment: Well, actually what you describe is what I expect BUT not what happens (read carefully the description): if I hit the async part, then hit it again 2 seconds later, the 2nd one arrives not 12 seconds after the beginning but 20!! It looks like there is no async there.

Comment: Hmm..that is certainly odd since I copied your code almost verbatim (it's missing an `import sys` at the top, but that's the only change I made). And running `time curl localhost:8080/async/ &` in the span of about 2 seconds showed both requests finished in 10 seconds. May I ask how were your requests to the endpoints made?

Comment: I did them through a browser (Firefox), not programmatically... Could it be the reason? I forgot to thank you for your help, so thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :). I wouldn't imagine it to be the browser per-se. But if, for example, the request is sent from the same tab, then indeed that would result in the behavior you encountered. For mor accurate timing, I would use `curl` (or whatever else is available from the command line.

Comment: You're right, with curl it works! The session handling, or anything else, through Firefox (I payed attention to use 2 separate tabs) must be disturbing... Many thanks!

Comment: Good to hear + glad I could help :).